# Why $g^i \not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

There is a website that defines a primitive root like this:

A primitive root is a number g in $Z_n^*$ such that {$g^1, g^2 ... g^{\varphi(n)}$} are all the numbers in $Z_n^*$.

Then, it goes on and talks about this property of primitive roots:

Given a primitive root g in $Z_n^*$, and a number $0<i<\varphi(n)$, $g^i\not\equiv1\pmod{n}$.

I understand why $g^{\varphi(n)}\equiv1\pmod{n}$, but why does that imply $g^i\not\equiv1\pmod{n}$?

Comment: The order of $g$ has to be equal to the order of $Z_n^*$, which is $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with group theory then you will get more comprehensible answers by revealing that.

Answer (score 1):

Because $g^1, g^2 ... g^{\varphi(n)}$ is a sequence of $\varphi(n)$ terms, and $\Bbb Z_n^*$ has $\varphi(n)$ elements. Since $g^{\varphi(n)}=1$, if any of the other $g^i$ are also equal to $1$, then the sequence $g^1, g^2 ... g^{\varphi(n)}$ doesn't have $\varphi(n)$ distinct terms, and thus cannot cover all of $\Bbb Z^*_n$, contradicting the primitiveness of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

That is because, by definition,  $g$ is a generator of the multiplicative groups $\;\mathbf Z^{\times}$, hence has order $\varphi(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists an $0<a<\phi(n)$ such that $g^a\equiv 1 \pmod n$

then $g^{a+1} \equiv g \pmod n$ and $g^{a+2} \equiv g^2 \pmod n$ etc.

and $g$ does not generate in fact generate $\mathbb Z_n^\times$ but some subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n^\times$

And $g$ is not a primitive.